# how to do Authentication in bug herd using curl

Tags: php, curl

here is sample code that i used to fetch project from api:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.bugherd.com/api_v2/projects.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('api key'));                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json= json_decode($result, true);
print_r($json);
```

output is here

```
Array
(
[error] => invalid api key
)
```

api key is  correct so where im wrong  in there api they have mention to fetch projects

```
curl -u api key:x https://www.bugherd.com/api_v2/organization.json
```

- here is the link of that api:https://www.bugherd.com/api_v2

Comment: Hmm I don't have your API key and IDs so how do I test ?

Comment: on placing api key output is coming but so please tell me where im wrong php code.

Comment: So what output you got when you ran this above code on the command line ?

Comment: out for project is on cmd:{"projects":[{"id":39923,"name":"bug herd addon"}],"meta":{"count":1}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a basic HTTP Authentication as the documentation of the API says..

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.bugherd.com/api_v2/projects.json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api key:x');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
$json= trim($return,'1');
$jsdecarr = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($jsdecarr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [projects] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39921
                    [name] => bugherd addon
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 40083
                    [name] => abcd
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 40250
                    [name] => fsdfgdg
                )

        )

    [meta] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: i have bug {"projects":[{"id":39921,"name":"bugherd addon"},{"id":40083,"name":"abcd"},{"id":40250,"name":"fsdfgdg"}],"meta":{"count":3}  without echo or print_r its returning this

Comment: i want to decode json reponse  i used: $json= json_decode($return, true); but not json data not decoded.

Comment: how to apply some  delay between in between sending call to server in curl any ides is most welcome.

Comment: Delay in the sense ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: sample code : while { //one request//  while{ //second request // } } i used sleep but not working actually in api

Comment: in api there is mention  You are only allowed to make an API call every 3 seconds. We therefore recommend to "sleep" your app for 3 seconds in between API calls to BugHerd to be safe. If you make more frequent API calls, a 403 error will be returned instead of the expected result.

Comment: Well you can use a sleep command then :) , `sleep(3000);` will make your script wait for 3 seconds. http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php